# ERROR: Cannot find module '.../node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v14-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, sqlite, ghost-blog

When I restarted my VPS and tried to start Ghost with 'npm start --production', I got this error. I tried to remove node_modules and reinstall them, but didn't fix it. I can only find node-v11-linux-x64 but not node-v14-linux-x64.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --production`?

Comment: @PatoSáinz Yes, I've tried that, but the error still exists.

Comment: We need must more information. What version of Linux are you running? How big is the VPS? What version of node are you running, exactly (node --version)?

Comment: @JTWebMan Since this problem had bothered me for several days, I decided to reinstall the OS on my VPS into ubuntu 14.04 ( the previous version was 15.04 ) and magically this problem doesn't exist.. I guess that there's something to do with 15.04? I am not quit sure..

Comment: I'm glad you found out a way to sort out your problem. However, I believe it'd be great to know a way to solve it without reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the node version. You might need to add the node 4.x ppa.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
npm install sqlite3
```

It's possible that you switch nodejs version and therefore the binding has been left from the previous version (i.e. v0.10.*). The error you are facing suggests that you have nodejs version v0.12.*. If that's the case, you can try switching nodejs version with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for example.

Comment: This actually worked for me, I have dependency in my package.json but somehow sqlite got installed instead of sqlite3, so running this solved it. Thanks.